AWS start sandbox from tutorial
I am following this tutorial:
https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/?ref=gsrchandson&id=updated
When I get to the part where I am supposed to run the sandbox using this commnad , ampx sandbox --profile default
I get an error :
TypeError: Invalid URL
Failed to construct URL with https://sts.[us-east-1].amazonaws.com TypeError: Invalid URL

my aws config looks like this:
[default]
sso_session = amplify-admin
sso_account_id = my-id
sso_role_name = AdministratorAccess
region = [us-east-1]
[sso-session amplify-admin]
sso_start_url = https://{some-guid}.awsapps.com/start
sso_region = us-east-1
sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access
[profile amplify-policy-my-id]
sso_session = amplify-admin
sso_account_id = my-id
sso_role_name = amplify-policy
region = [us-east-1]

What am I missing?

Can you create an IAM user with AdministratorAccess-Amplify IAM policy, and use its credentials in AWS profile file? With that way, you won't get into these trouble.

The problem are the brackets around the region in the AWS config file:
It should be us-east-1 instead of [us-east-1]

Thank you, but I didn't configure that. It is generated by the packages in node_modules. I don't know which configuration I am missing

@Moutabreath this is configured in your aws config. You should remove brackets from region

Note to self: Read the answer better! Thank you very much!

@Moutabreath I edited the answer to make it more clear it's in the AWS config file, after your previous comment
